# Angular Infinite Scroll: scroll bar on body not on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I implementing infinite scroll in my web app using angularjs. I found this useful directive on net [Infinite Scroll](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/03/infinite-scroll-for-facebook-like-pagination-angularjs.html), but the problem is this can only be implemented inside div not in the scroll bar body:

```
app.directive('infinityscroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('scroll', function () {
                if ((element[0].scrollTop + element[0].offsetHeight) == element[0].scrollHeight) {
                    //scroll reach to end
                    scope.$apply(attrs.infinityscroll)
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my html codes:

```
<div infinityscroll="NextPage()" style="height:700px; overflow:auto;" >
  <div ng-repeat="item  in listItems">
       <img ng-src="{{item.picture}}" alt="broken" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

when i remove the inline css it won't work.so how can i change the infinite scroll in the body instead of div?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that inline styling is to notify infinite scroll when its supposed to fetch next set of data (for consecutive page).
Do you want to define that height at body level ??

Comment: i don't want to use the div scroll bar. i need to use the scroll bar on body which is the main scroll bar in a browser.

Comment: I saw somewhere and it works, it will change your css style if not: html,body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
} and add infinite-scroll-container="'body'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`<body infinityscroll="NextPage()" style="height: 1000px; overflow:auto;">`
and remove infinitescroll initialization from your div.

You might need to adjust height a bit, based on your screen-size.
Hope this solves your issue.. :)

Comment: sorry but i tried it before but it's not working.. thank you anyway. ;)